# Date model for commenting system stored in a key-value NoSQL DB?

Tags: database-design, nosql, cassandra

I'm trying to leverage Cassandra's strong support for time series data to build a commenting system.

So far I'm thinking that each row would be a particular topic, and each comment would be a new column, stored in event_time descending order such that I could get the latest replies.

```
CREATE TABLE topic (
    topic_id text,
    user_id text,
    event_time timestamp,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (topic_id,event_time),
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);
```

However, if I want to get the last 10 comments made by 'John' for example, this seems to be difficult with the current model.

Could anyone give any advice on how I could retrieve 'John's comments efficiently, and if I would have to change the data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cassandra you need to take a query-based modeling approach.  In your case, I would create a similarly-structured query table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE topicbyuser (
    topic_id text,
    user_id text,
    event_time timestamp,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id,event_time),
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);
```

And then, if you wanted to query for the last 10 comments made by John, this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM topicbyuser WHERE user_id='John' LIMIT 10;
```

You could also add an `ORDER BY`, but since you have that in your column family definition, you shouldn't need it.  Also, you should note that this query table does not replace the original `topic` table.  It works in conjunction *with* it.

Comment: Thank you. If however, a user wants to update their comment, I would have to update both tables right? Since transactions are not fully supported, how would you handle edge cases in which one table is updated, but the other fails?

Comment: @AlbertLim For those `UPDATE`s, you should be able to encapsulate them with the `BEGIN BATCH`/`APPLY BATCH` statements.  That will tell Cassandra to apply them as a single, logical operation.  Check this SO answer for more info on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818576/insert-multiple-records-at-once-in-cassandra/26818803#26818803